# Extrude curve along its normal in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I need to extrude this curve along its normal in Geometry Nodes.

Instanced lines are for visualization only.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am not totally sure, do you mean like this?

[image]

or do you really wanna extrude like this?

[image]

Comment: Yes, like the second one, thank you very much Chris! I had tried that but I must have done something wrong.